# After removing an element from array using splice. its not resetting.Is my code has any mistake

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

A drop down contains an array value. If i select one value from drop down it will remove that value from array its working. But on click of reset button it should reset with old values .Here is my code

HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="exerciseTypeCtrl">
   <select id="exerciseSuperCategory" data-role="listview" ng-options="Lay.id as Lay.value for Lay in Layer " ng-model="itemsuper" ng-change="changeData(itemsuper)">
   </select> 
   <input type="button" ng-click="resetLayer()" value="Reset"/>        

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

angularjs controler code

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('exerciseTypeCtrl',function($scope)
{

    $scope.Layer = [
        { id: 1, value: '0.38'},
        { id: 2, value: '0.76'},
        { id: 3, value: '1.14'},
        { id: 4, value: '1.52'},
        { id: 5, value: '1.9'},
        { id: 6, value: '2.28'},
        { id: 7, value: '2.66'},
        { id: 8, value: '3.04'},
        { id: 9, value: '3.42'},
        { id: 10, value:'3.8'},
        { id: 11, value: '4.18'},
        { id: 12, value: '4.56'}
    ];

     $scope.changeData = function(value)
      {

         var coating = $scope.Layer;
         if(coating != null)
         {
                var j = coating.length;                                 
                while(j>0)
                {
                    j =j-1;
                    var make = coating[j]['id'];    
                    var present = 0;


                        if(make == value)
                        {                                                           
                          coating.indexOf(make);
                          coating.splice(j,1);                        
                        }

                }
         }
      }
      $scope.resetLayer -function()
      {
          $scope.Layer =  $scope.Layer;
      }

});
</script>
```

using splice i am removing the dropdown selected value. but on click of button its not resetting

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$scope.resetLayer -function()` --> `$scope.resetLayer = function()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a copy of variable while you intialize/get `Layer` data

```
var copyOfLayer = angular.copy($scope.Layer);
```

Then while reseting it you need to do assign old array to the `$scope.Layer` also you need to rewrite your `resetLayer` function to below

```
  $scope.resetLayer = function() {
    $scope.Layer = angular.copy(copyOfLayer)
  }
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kmvO19mPf0cNZAmJysU3?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Mistake is here:

```
$scope.resetLayer -function()
```

**Should be**

```
 $scope.resetLayer =function()
```

I am formatting your code:

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('exerciseTypeCtrl',function($scope)
{

    $scope.Layer = [
        { id: 1, value: '0.38'},
        { id: 2, value: '0.76'},
        { id: 3, value: '1.14'},
        { id: 4, value: '1.52'},
        { id: 5, value: '1.9'},
        { id: 6, value: '2.28'},
        { id: 7, value: '2.66'},
        { id: 8, value: '3.04'},
        { id: 9, value: '3.42'},
        { id: 10, value:'3.8'},
        { id: 11, value: '4.18'},
        { id: 12, value: '4.56'}
    ];

var resetArray = $scope.Layer;

     $scope.changeData = function(value)
      {

         var coating = $scope.Layer;
         if(coating != null)
         {
                var j = coating.length;                                 
                while(j>0)
                {
                    j =j-1;
                    var make = coating[j]['id'];    
                    var present = 0;


                        if(make == value)
                        {                                                           
                          coating.indexOf(make);
                          coating.splice(j,1);                        
                        }

                }
         }
      }
      $scope.resetLayer =function()
      {
          $scope.Layer = restArray;

      }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have done a mistake in this line where you are assigning your function to the `resetLayer` variable

```
$scope.resetLayer -function(){}
```

This should instead be

```
$scope.resetLayer =function(){};
```

Enjoy!

Comment: sorry thats my mistake